# Need help creating a function in JavaScript to return an HTML video link

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to create a function to accept the src, width, and controls for a video to put into an HTML document with a `<video></video>` tag, no whitespace, a space between arguments, and any single quotes changed to double quotes, and return a cleaned up, properly formatted version of the input. If there is no input for width and/or control, I do not want to display those parameters.

```
function createVideo(src, width, controls) {
  let dataSrc = src.replace(/,+/g, ", ").replace(/"+/g).replace(/\s+/, "");
  let dataWidth = width.replace(/,+/g, ", ").replace(/"+/g).replace(/\s+/, "");
  let dataControls = controls
    .replace(/,+/g, ", ")
    .replace(/"+/g)
    .replace(/\s+/, "");
  let cleanedVid = dataSrc + dataWidth + dataControls;
  let resultAll =
    "<video src=" +
    dataSrc +
    " " +
    dataWidth +
    "  " +
    dataControls +
    "></video>";
  let resultNoWidth =
    "<video src=" + dataSrc + " " + dataControls + "></video>";
  let resultNoControls =
    "<video src=" + dataSrc + " " + dataWidth + "></video>";
  let resultOne = "<video src=" + dataSrc + "></video>";

  if (typeof cleanedVid[1] === Number && cleanedVid[2] === "controls") {
    result = resultAll;
  }

  if (cleanedVid[1] === "") {
    result = resultNoWidth;
  }

  if (cleanedVid[1] === Number && cleanedVid[2] === "") {
    result = resultNoControls;

    if (cleanedVid[1] === "" && cleanedVid[2] === "") {
      result = resultOne;
    }

    return result;
  }
}

console.log(
  createVideo(
    "http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4",
    " ",
    "controls"
  )
);
```

With this, I'm getting back undefined.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What do you want to achieve by running `split` on an array?

Comment: you could also format your code a bit better, kinda hard to understand anything like that

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you are passing the 3 parameters as one single parameter. Pass as 3 separate parameters and you can do away with all the pre-processing of the string. (It's even more unclear why you put the parameters into an array and then try to `split` the array.)

Also, using `document.createElement`, instead of building a string, simplifies things.

```js
function createVideo(src, width, controls) {
  let video = document.createElement("video");
  video.src = src;
  if (width) video.width = width;
  if (controls) video.controls = controls;
  document.body.appendChild(video);
}
createVideo("http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4", 500, true);
```